# Shifting values with np.apply_along_axis returns inconsistent results

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, feature-engineering

TL;DR: `np.apply_along_axis` works for a certain array with shape `(1561, 338)` which is a subset of another array with shape `(351225, 338)` for which it fails.

I am trying to apply the following function:

```
def add_min(a):
    return a + abs(a.min()) if a.min() < 0 else a
```

`x_train` has shape `(1561, 15, 15, 338)` (*n* * *height* * *width* * *channels*) and I need to shift all values to positive to be able to log normalize my data. I want to do that per channel, for obvious reasons.

Now if I reshape x_train: `x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 338)` and get shape `(351225, 338)`
I should be able to perform:

```
x_train = np.apply_along_axis(add_min, 0, x_train)
```

However...

Before:

```
x_train.min()
>> -2147483648
```

After:

```
x_train.min()
>> -2147370103
```

In other words, it does not work. On the other hand, if I only keep the center pixel:

```
# Keep the center value of axes (1, 2)
x_train = x_train[:, x_train.shape[1]//2, x_train.shape[2]//2, :]
x_train.shape
>> (1561, 338)

x_train.min()
>> -32768  # strange coincidence that this location in the image has a much smaller value range 

x_train = np.apply_along_axis(add_min, 0, x_train)
x_train.min()
>> 0
```

I think it has something to do with the large negative values, because if I select random indices in the 2 center axes (i.e. 1 and 8) instead of the middle (7, 7) I again get `x_train.min()` of -2147483648  and -2147369934, before and after `np.apply_along_axis`, respectively.

So what am I doing wrong? Is there a better way I can achieve my goal?

Comment: I sort of hate `apply_along_axis`.  It has too many subtleties, and does not offer any speed improvments.  For a 2d array it is faster to just iterate on the 'other' axis.  For 3 and 4d arrays, it simplifies the 'nesting' that more explicit looping requires, but that's it.  Don't waste too much time trying to make it work.

Comment: What is the data type of `x_train`?  Suspiciously, -32768 is the smallest value for an int16 (hex 0x8000).  -2147483648 is the smallest value for an int32 (0x80000000).

Comment: @TimRoberts the dtype is int32 in all cases. You might be on to something.

Comment: Can't you adjust the whole array?  `if x_train.min() < 0:` / `x_train -= x_train.min()`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overflow on `int32` is a good guess if the problem is "random".  But using `apply_along_axis` may be making it harder to diagnose the issue, since it's wrapping your function in an (obscure) iteration.  It should be easier to diagnose things with whole array calculations.

Make a modest array a mix of `min` values:

```
In [77]: A = np.random.randint(-50,1000,(4,8))
In [78]: A
Out[78]: 
array([[151, 531, 765, 379,  89, 499, 818, 848],
       [873, -12, -45, 900, 416, 838, 603, 849],
       [540,   0,   1, 589, 297, 566, 688, 556],
       [ 53, 170, 461, -16,  -6, 480, 321, 392]])
```

Your function:

```
In [79]: np.apply_along_axis(add_min, 0, A)
Out[79]: 
array([[151, 543, 810, 395,  95, 499, 818, 848],
       [873,   0,   0, 916, 422, 838, 603, 849],
       [540,  12,  46, 605, 303, 566, 688, 556],
       [ 53, 182, 506,   0,   0, 480, 321, 392]])
```

Let's create an whole-array equivalent. First find the `min` with a `axis` specification:

```
In [80]: am = np.min(A, axis=0, keepdims=True)
In [81]: am
Out[81]: array([[ 53, -12, -45, -16,  -6, 480, 321, 392]])
```

Now create a shift array that imitates your function (without the `if` that only works for scalars):

```
In [82]: shift=np.abs(am)
In [83]: shift[am>=0]=0
In [84]: shift
Out[84]: array([[ 0, 12, 45, 16,  6,  0,  0,  0]])
In [85]: A+shift
Out[85]: 
array([[151, 543, 810, 395,  95, 499, 818, 848],
       [873,   0,   0, 916, 422, 838, 603, 849],
       [540,  12,  46, 605, 303, 566, 688, 556],
       [ 53, 182, 506,   0,   0, 480, 321, 392]])
```

There are other ways of getting that shift, but the same basic idea applies, using the `am<0` to determine which columns get the shift.

This will also be faster.